# Yii RBAC on per Model Record basis

Tags: yii, rbac

I am new to Yii and not familiar with the RBAC feature of Yii. My question is, Is it possible to use RBAC on per Model record basis e.g.:

Table Project_users:

```
| user_id | project_id | role  |
================================
|    1    |      1      | admin |   
---------------------------------
|    1    |      2      | member|
```

In this scenario, user 1 can edit project 1 but not project 2. Can I use Yii's RBAC feature here with minimal configuration or do I need to create my own filter code?

Comment: did you see [the post in yii docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/136/getting-to-understand-hierarchical-rbac-scheme) ?

Comment: Not yet, thanks for the link. i'll check it

Comment: Just read it, but there's nothing related  to what i want to implement. Basically, i'd like the `Yii::app()->user->checkAccess` to check from a Model record, not from `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

I provided a response for a similar question here : [Yii RBAC: access to specific items/rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588031/yii-rbac-access-to-specific-items-rows/)

This allows you to create custom filter rules in a few steps :

1. specify the 'accessControl' flag in your filters() override method.
2. In your accessRules() method, specify a reference to your custom function to perform the access control check
3. Create your access control function to perform your checks and return true or false accordingly to specify if the access is allowed or disallowed.

You can see the code examples in the linked question.

Comment: Hi crafter, i follwed the link to your answer but i dont think it will check from a table other than the users. I dig deeper into the Yii's code, and it looks like i need to create a new component that extends either the `CDbAuthManager` or `CAuthManager` and assign the tablenames and override methods.

Comment: Since the validation happens in a custom method, you can pretty much decide what table to read from.